# Python Tkinter packages

Tags: package-management

I'm having some difficulty finding information on which packages I need to use Tkinter.

The software centre shows IDLE ... I don't think it's the same thing.

Synaptic package manager lists numerous "tk" packages - which do I need ?

I tried removing and reinstalling : sudo apt-get install tk8.5

Could there be a miss-match with my Python version 2.7.4 ?

Nick

Answer (score 2):

The packages are `python3-tk` and `python-tk`. If you are writing new code, it is probably better to write Python 3 based code, instead of Python 2.x code.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's installed correctly now because I can write "from Tkinter import *" - however "from Tkinter import ttk" does not work. Maybe the book I'm learning from is outdated.